# Traversing through a linked list in C, get caught in Loop

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, linked-list, infinite-loop

I keep getting caught in a loop but i dont know how to fix it.  We have to traverse through the list.  It prints but it doesn't move on to the next test function.  I don't think the code is recognizing the end of the list and isn't exiting the while loop.

```
void traverse_int(struct s_node* head)
{
    struct s_node* next_node;
    int* x;
    next_node=head;

    while(next_node != NULL)
    {
        if (next_node->elem == NULL)
        {
            my_str("NULL");
        }
        else
        {
            x=(int*) next_node->elem;
            my_int(*x);
        }
        my_str(" ");
        next_node=next_node->next;

    }
    my_char('\n');
}
```

this is the test case that i am using:

```
    a = 17;
    b = 10;
    c = 16;
    d = 95;
    add_elem(&a, &head);
    add_elem(&b, &head);
    add_elem(&c, &head);=
    add_elem(&d, &head);
    traverse_int(head);              my_str("\nshould print 95 16 10 17\n");
```

It does not print my_str it just gets caught and prints:
95 16 10 17

it should print:

95 16 10 17

should print 95 16 10 17

Please help!!

Comment: Note that the problem is most likely in `add_elem()` and you've not shown us `add_elem()` code (hence the comment about missing an MCVE ([MCVE])).  You also don't show how `head` is initialized, nor the structure for `struct s_node` (which, while we can guess about its content, we shouldn't have to).  Your test case code has a blatant typo at the `=` after `add_elem(&c, &head);=`.  We can guess that `my_str(const char *str)` is analogous to `printf("%s\n", str);` but maybe we shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm old but with link lists like your stack thing here I see you need to assign a NULL value to the tail of your linked list first and then every time a node is added then add a NULL to the new tail.  You did not assign a NULL value to your end node so you have an endless loop.